# Large left white-space in home list of questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

Chrome Version 48.0.2547.0 canary (64-bit) on OS X 10.11.1

I would I could give the exact steps to replicate, but I have not been able to isolate this behavior - it only happens on the home tab.  A large blank white space shows up on the left of the question list.

These are the steps I took that reproduce the issue after some time:

- Navigate to stackoverflow.com
- Click on another tab
- Click on the drop down
- Click on home
- Click on a tag
- Delete the new tag
- Click on another tab
- Go to home

[image: Massive empty space on the left side of the home tab]

Worth noting, when this happens the `#qlist-wrapper` element is duplicated:

[image: #qlist-wrapper duplicated in the DOM]